# Update both sides of a UISplitView Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I have a feeling I know the answer to this question but want to confirm my thoughts.

If I am wrong a pointer would really help as I have been messing with code, as well as searching the web for the last several hours.

I have a NSTimer updating several views via a delegate on a set timeframe.

I thought it would look nice to place my views into a split view on an iPad as well as the iPhone 6 Plus. I successfully moved my views into a split view controller however when I rotate the device only one side is updated via the delegate (master is updated or detail is updated) depending on where I was in the app when I rotate the device. That side continues to Update while the device is in the "Split View Mode". If I click on a new row in the master and the master was updating (detail was not) then the detail starts updating and the master stops.

My guess is that because the delegate is firing on the main queue to update a view (only way to update a view as far as I know) that it is only updating the view that is currently set as active (IE the master even though it is visible is not on the main queue if I rotated when I was looking at what becomes the detail view). Is this the case? can you not fire an update on both sides of a split view simultaneously?

Again I am looking more for is it possible? I have my app working in portrait as expected, I just wanted to make it a bit more universal and use real estate better by adding a split view. If I can't update both sides of a split view at the same time I will rethink the path I am trying to go down.

Edit:
thanks for the answers. To clarify what I am doing I am going to add some code:

```
protocol MasterTimerDelegate {
    func masterTimerDidUpdate(item: Item, forGroup group: Group)
    func masterTimerDidUpdateAllItems()
    func masterTimerDidUpdateProgressForItem(item: Item, forGroup group: Group, withProgressCompleted progress: Double)

}
```

Then both ViewControllers whether they are in the MasterView Area or the DetailView area are implementing that Delegate

The MasterTimer Class is firing an NSTimer every 1sec right now for testing and I am having it update labels, and various other components.

Here is an example of the code I have on what should be the DetailSide of the splitView.

```
func masterTimerDidUpdate(item: Item, forGroup group: Group) {
        if group == self.group {

            let rowToUpdate = group.items.indexOf(item)
            let newPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: rowToUpdate!, inSection: 0)
            if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(newPath) as? ItemCell {
                cell.configureDurationLabelForItem(item)
            }   
        }
}
```

I have something similar on the MasterView Side of things. I am setting the masterTimer.delegate = self in the view did load of the ViewControllers I want to update. I can't think of any other place I would put that as it is my understanding from the two answers/hints already provided are implying that if the View is active on screen it is loaded up and doesn't leave memory so the masterTimer.delegate should be listening regardless while the View is being presented.

Update #2:
I tried setting up a notification for device rotation like this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "didRotate:", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

in my didRotate I have the following:

```
func didRotate(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("device rotated")
        selectedCellIndexPath = nil
        masterTimer.delegate = self
        self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I also added a print statement on the delegate method above to see if it is firing. The delegate is firing when the device is in Portrait. It is also firing if I select a cell in the master view to show my group view. but it is not firing if I have what will become the master view on screen when in portrait and switch to landscape. The notification is firing on rotation but the delegate seems to not be listening anymore as the print statement is not firing after rotation.

Comment: Not sure a timer running every second is the best solution (wouldn't that block the main UI thread?). Can you tie the changes to a different event? Also, as a test try making the interval a bit longer and see if the delegates fire in both places.

Comment: My plan is to change the timer to fire at 1min but I am inpatient to wait that long while I am trying to figure out why I can't get both views to update. As best I can tell though having the timer fire every second is not adversely affecting the user experience even if it is blocking the main thread with what I am doing. I can't notice any lag

Comment: tried 10 sec interval and both are not updating

Comment: Are you instantiating two different objects to be delegated which you are then setting in each view controller or is it one object with two delegates? Also after you remove the NSTimer component, consider filing this as a bug report at Apple if the normal [delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) pattern is not working

Comment: I would set up the Notification observer in viewDidLoad.

Comment: I am instantiating One Object that both Views are listening for. The one object is instantiated in the AppDelegate when The app enters the foreground as this object is my master timer and I want to kill the timer when the app leaves the foreground to be a good citizen. The MasterView is looking for the updateAll delegate method and the detail view is looking for the specific item delegate method

Comment: I know this sounds simple ~ double check your selector names on the delegate or make both listen for the same notification. (just as a test)

Comment: That is all fine and confirmed. Only thing I haven't tried was doing a custom split view controller class and setting the delegate to that. I was going to try that when I get back to my computer this afternoon

Answer (score 0):

Views don't really exist on a queue, main or otherwise - all UIViews, visible or not, need to be updated on the main queue because of the graphics systems underlying them...

It seems more like for some reason one side just doesn't know it should be updating, possibly because you are relying on something like viewWillAppear being called and it is not?

At any rate, you should be able to update any views at any time.

Comment: Kendall thanks for the answer. I updated the question with some code. I am using Protocols and delegates to listen for the change. It works when not in split view (iPhone Portrait) but not in split view as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to either use NSNotification or protocols to notify each view controller when the views need to be updated (including their orientation, etc). Simply posting a notification that certain events have occurred will allow you to have each view controller do the right thing for itself.

Comment: Tommie, I updated my question with code. I am using protocols on what I call the MasterTimer class that is calling a delegate. If I understand your answer this is the correct way to do what I want but as I mentioned when I have both views on screen listening to the delegate only one of them us updating.

Answer (score 0):

So after some more hunting my understanding of a delegate is a bit off. I thought it was a notification queue and everything was listening. Turns out NotificationCenter does what I want not a delegate. Notification Center is the messaging queue in iOS that anything that is in memory can listen to the queue and if they know what to do with the message they act on it. Posting this answer for others as I had a hard time finding this answer.